Print composer rendering WMS layer in different order to map view
I am working with a WMS layer for Source Protection Zones in QGIS. In the main map window, the WMS renders in the correct order, with the red area shown (first image).
However, in the second screenshot, the WMS layer has rendered in a different order, and the red area no longer shows. The WMS is added as a PNG layer.
Can I do anything to control the rendering order and make sure the red area shows on my final output?



The WMS originates from here, for anyone else wanting to try: https://environment.data.gov.uk/dataset/6fd0120f-d465-11e4-abee-f0def148f590

the dpi will have changed that might well change the scaledenominator  for that layer. check the network debug plugin and see what is being requested and if it works in your broesrr

You're right, when I change (check) the scale, I do get a scale where the red zone renders. But this also limits me to only using certain scales. I'm not sure this is intended behaviour from QGIS...

It is the intended behaviour of the WMS as set by it's owner

@IanTurton Can this be overriden via QGIS? It might seem intentional in the code, but based on my interpretation, it is not helpful and likely erroneous.

A WMS can specify a range of scales that it will display at, there is nothing you can do to change that. In this case the EA have specified  that it won't draw at the one you want

Which could be intentional I suppose, if there's some desire to stop people getting too much detail on the exact location of a source of drinking water, for security reasons. (Even though we all know it can be worked around to be able to zoom in with rendering turned off, etc.)

Looking at the WMS capabilities response in this case though there is no advertised scale limitations https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/source-protection-zones-merged/wms?Service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities it could still be happening through the SLD though.

For a single GetMap request with multiple layers rendering order is dependent on the order you have the layers within the layers parameter value.
As per the WMS API 1.3.0 specification section 7.3.3.3

A WMS shall render the requested layers by drawing the leftmost in the list bottommost, the next one over that, and so on.

